# Excel to .tsv file but still got comma and quote

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm trying to create a new .tsv file by running below code. But the output is still in .csv file eventhough i have set it to .tsv. Is there any way to solve this?

```
Sub toTxt()
    Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\PO" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhmmss") & ".tsv"
    iLast = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO_Master").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO_Master").Range("A7:BA" & iLast)
    Open myFile For Output As #2
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value

            If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
                Write #2, cellValue
            Else
                Write #2, cellValue,
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Close #2
```

Sample output

```
ASA,"AA","BB","CC","DD","EE","FF"
```

Comment: You're using `Write` not `Print` to create your file so this will automatically insert commas between values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building up a string `outputline` (you'll need to declare that) and only write the data each **row**.

```
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    outputline = ""
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value

        If outputline = "" Then
            outputline = outputline & cellValue
        Else
            outputline = outputline & Chr(9) & cellValue
        End If

    Next j
    Print #2, outputline

Next i
```

Comment: Thank you. Your method works. But the only problem now is it the column number cannot exceed 65 column. Do you know why?

Comment: Nothing in there should cause that. When it errors, what is the length of `outputline`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. There is column with "#####" value. So it will cause error. Do you know how to print the output as text format? Because I have value start with 00001 but when convert to .tsv file, it only show 1

Comment: Hi @Apis , I don't recognise that issue to be honest.. perhaps it's worth raising a new question that simply asks when reading a `cell.value` how to deal with the `#######` issue.